# How can I get a clojure "def" to re-evaluate without using :reload?

Tags: clojure

How can I get a clojure "def" to re-evaluate without using :reload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(def x 0)
x   ; => 0
(def x 1)
x   ; => 1
```

You can't re-def a var from another namespace, so you should switch to it's namespace with in-ns before re-defing.

Comment: note: if your doing that you should be 100% sure that there is no better way.

Comment: Does this mean you would would have to "eval" the def again?

Comment: Yes. If you are on slime, you just change def in source code and evaluate it with C-x C-e.

Answer (score 2):

You can also call load or load-file at the repl.

```
(load-file "foo/bar.clj")
(load "foo/bar")
```